# Manage permission in phonegap android

Tags: android, cordova, android-permissions, phonegap-desktop-app, phonegap-cli

When we try to restrain permission list asked at application installation no one of our try does work.

We try to add

```
<preference name="permissions" value="none"/>
```

in /config.xml Should we put it in www/config.xml (there is no file with this name actually)
we putted it directly in sub path in patch
example

```
<widget xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:gap="http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0" id="com.mycompany.mobile" version="1.0.1">
  <preference name="permissions" value="none"/>
```

Comment: It should be in the www folder, because when you are converting the HTML to .APK you would ZiP the www folder.

Comment: @roduce could you please elaborate what you are trying to acheive?

Comment: I try to ask for no permissions for my application. The only "permission" i need is for it to access the web for requesting a json from our server.

I do not found where to update permission management.
I tried to put the xml file inside www and it still ask fro all permission when installing